# How to work with Dynamic tables using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, data-access-layer

I will try to explain my situation; I have around 30 tables in my database out of these 30 one table (say x) is partially dynamic, when I say partially I mean that more columns can be added this table “x” but cannot be deleted. Once the user chooses to and more columns he should be able to do this from the frontend itself without getting the developer involved. I have designed my DAL in NHibernate, now the question is how do I achieve dynamic DAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic components](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-dynamic) to get those properties mapped to a dictionary.

Remember you'll have to rebuild your SessionFactory when you add a column to the mapping, but that shouldn't be a big issue, as it won't probably happen very often.